# Yahoo Pipes: filter whole word only?

Tags: rss, yahoo-pipes

This is a very simple question but its difficult for me to answer myself because I am testing my pipe with rss feeds that are always changing. So here it goes:

I want to filter out rss posts with profanity in it.

```
BLOCK - ANY
item.title contains ****
```

But when I use a filter containing a word that is found commonly within others (the word ass is found in tallahassee) it blocks those as well. Is there any way I can just filter out the whole word and nothing else?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is another way to do it but you could easily use a regular expression in the filter to match the whole word. Following the "ass" theme this should work.

```
(?i)\bass\b
```

The `(?i)` means the regular expression is case insensitive, the `\b` indicate word boundaries.

If this is to be a set of words that you are filtering out you can add multiple options in Yahoo! Pipes or combine them in a single regular expression.

```
(?i)\b(ass|asses)\b
```

Comment: I tested this and it wasn't working. Anything I might be doing wrong?

Comment: @jordaninternets Can you provide a link to your Yahoo! Pipe at all to look at?

Comment: Here it is: http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=2650028af6968121fb0543d0af2a2c21